# How do I calculate q/m?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, atoms

My chemistry book (Mortimer in German) has the following question:

Calculate the value q/m for the following Ions:

[image]

("mit Masse" meaning "with mass")

How do I calculate q/m?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the first part has a charge of $+1$, that is it is a Hydrogen atom, in which an electron (actually it's only electron) is removed. Since the charge of an electron in $\pu{1.60 x 10^-19 C}$, and the mass of the Ion (as given per the question) is $\pu{1.67 x 10^-27 kg}$ [I prefer working in the SI units, you should be able to convert to any desired measurement system].

For this case, $$\frac{q}{m} \approx \pu{9.6 x 10^7 C kg-1}$$ Use the same logic for the other parts of the question.

Comment: You can use ```$\pu{}$``` for physical units. Also, I like how you say you prefer working in SI and then use kg.. :o